# "Different language linkage" — warning in xcode 4, error in xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, xcode5

On a Unity iOS project I work on, there was a "different language linkage" issue; it was a warning in xcode 4, but became an error in xcode 5.

```
/.../Libraries/SomeFile.mm:145:10: Declaration of 'SomeMethod' has a different language linkage
```

Here's the file:

```
void SomeMethod(const char* _List);

...

extern "C"
{
    void SomeMethod(const char* _List)
    ...
}
```

How can I fix it, or, at least (since it's not really that important and it would be nice to be able to build something at least), make it once again a warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the **declaration** in `extern "C"` not the definition. To be sure, you can wrap both in it. (Although, if I recall correctly, just doing the declaration should be enough to inform the compiler of your intent for the definition.) Like so:

```
extern "C"
{
    void SomeMethod(const char* _List);
}

...

extern "C"
{
    void SomeMethod(const char* _List)
    ...
}
```